# advance search to show post by date

Tags: theming

i trying to make the search on drupal show result by date. for example if i type 25/05/2010 it should return posts for that date and also search by key work which is default on the search. how can i acheive that.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
    $result_node = $variables['result']['node'];
    $image_realpath="";
    if(!empty($result_node->field_op_main_image)){
        $image_field = $result_node->field_op_main_image;
        $image_realpath = file_create_url($image_field['und']['0']['uri']);
    }
    $variables['image_uri'] = $image_realpath;
    $author_name="";
    $info = "";
    if(!empty($result_node->field_op_author)){
        $author = $result_node->field_op_author;
        $lang = $result_node->language;
        $author_id = $author[$lang]['0']['nid'];
        $author_detail = node_load($author_id);
        $author_name = $author_detail->title;
        $info .= $author_name . ' - ';
    }
    if(!empty($result_node->field_date)){
        $date_obj = $result_node->field_date;
        $date_val = $date_obj['und']['0']['value'];
        $info .= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date_val));
    }
    $variables['info'] = $info;
    // dpm($variables);
```

above is the code for displaying my result for now.

please help thanks

```
=======================================================================
```

EDITED

so this is what i got so far: let me try to explain:

i was trying to modify the search-form and the search-block-form i was able to add a jquery date picker so that the user might search for a specific date or a key word.

the date picker is working

now the issue is:

when i search for key words and press submit it return the article with key word. but if i enter date only it give error to enter keyword and if i enter keyword and date it search by keyword only and ignore the date

code is below

// function to modify search form
function fiveplus_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

```
// $variables['form']['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'search';
if((array_key_exists('#id', $form) && $form['#id'] == 'search-block-form')){
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = '';
}
if((array_key_exists('#id', $form) && $form['#id'] == 'search-form')){


    $form['basic']['submit']['#value'] = 'submit';
    $form['basic']['keys']['date_field']['#title'] = 'search';
    $form['basic']['date_field'] = array('#type' => 'date_popup','#date_format' => 'Y-m-d');
    dpm($form_state);
    //$form['advanced'] ;
}
```

so anyone can help me figure out how to make a user be able to search only by 1. date 2. date and keyword 3. keyword

thank you

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using views module?

Comment: am not sure how to do it in view?? Will it give user the option to pick a date and search ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use views to search all of your content.

Rather than me write out every step for you, Please try the tutorial at http://webwash.net/tutorials/how-create-search-pages-using-views-drupal-7